# Github action: setup-java with multiple JDKs and corresponding environment variables

Tags: java, github-actions

**Background:**
I've a spring-boot 2.3 project using reactive driver for cassandra that is built on Java 11. For integration test though, when I spin up an embedded Cassandra database, I rely on presence of Java 8 on the machine with accompanying environment variable JAVA8_HOME.

**Question:**
How can I configure GitHub action [setup-java](https://github.com/actions/setup-java) to utilise multiple JDKs for my build and let JAVA_HOME point to Java 11 but JAVA8_HOME point to Java8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using multiple JDKs with GitHub actions is already possible today. One great and neat way is to leverage the [strategy.matrix](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstrategymatrix) job configuration like that in your `.github/workflows/maven.yml`:

```
name: github

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        java-version: [ 8, 11, 15 ]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: ${{ matrix.java-version }}
    - run: mvn -B install --no-transfer-progress --file pom.xml
```

I didn't check if this does include the environment variable configuration for `JAVA_HOME` you need - but it clearly isolates the build environments for the separate Java versions. Here's a full example project using this setup: https://github.com/codecentric/cxf-spring-boot-starter and [here's a green build log](https://github.com/codecentric/cxf-spring-boot-starter/actions/runs/468949251).

Also the GitHub actions GUI for matrix builds is quite nice:
[image: github actions matrix build]

Comment: The question is about using 2 different JDKs in the same build, one for compilation, another for test execution. Matrix configs don't provide that.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly setup-java, but you can try another java-install action: https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/install-jdk#multiple-jdks. Use `target` property for setting up env var to use as `JAVA_HOME`.